# How to search the id of imagebuttons?

Tags: android, search, imagebutton

I created a plenty of imagebuttons, and I want to search for them in the same activity.

I don't know how to search for imagebutton ids.
Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Make an `ArrayList` and as you create the ImageButtons add them to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `findViewById` method:

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You should set id in your xml file:

```
android:id="@+id/button1"
```

Or, if you create `ImageButton`s programmatically, you can do like this:

```
button1 = new ImageButton(activity);
button1.setId("button1");
```

And use `findViewById` later on.